# Add SSL certificate to docker container with ASP .NET app to connect cosmosDB simulator in host machine

Tags: asp.net, docker, ssl

I am adding a cosmosdb simulator certificate in a linux docker container with my app ASP .NET. I want connect my app on a container with my windows 10 host machine. I have the next issue:

```
project-cosmos-container |       Initializing repository: database KeyDatabase, collection KeyConatiner
project-cosmos-container |
project-cosmos-container | Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.) ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

So I edit my dockerfile to copy my certificate that I export previusly following these steps https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator-export-ssl-certificates#certification-rotation.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime
# We create the folder inside the container
WORKDIR /local-project

# We are coping all project executables that we created with dotnet build and dotnet publish 
COPY ./bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/publish/* ./
COPY ./wwwroot/cer/*.cer /etc/ssl/certs/

EXPOSE 80 433
RUN update-ca-certificates

# We indicate to execute the program in the executable of the project
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Local.Proyect.Core.dll"]
```

And I have the following logs of docker:

```
Step 1/7 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime                   
 ---> ccf4063f0898                                                        
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /local-project                                         
 ---> Using cache                                                         
 ---> 4bafaaa39da1                                                        
Step 3/7 : COPY ./bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/publish/* ./                  
 ---> b641fbfe771e                                                        
Step 4/7 : COPY ./wwwroot/cer/documentdbemulatorcert.cer /etc/ssl/certs/  
 ---> 003052fba9ff                                                        
Step 5/7 : EXPOSE 80 433                                                  
 ---> Running in 88619ba67f33                                             
Removing intermediate container 88619ba67f33                              
 ---> d5b467fa7820                                                        
Step 6/7 : RUN update-ca-certificates                                     
 ---> Running in 890e73a506f4                                             
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...                                
0 added, 0 removed; done.                                                 
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...                         
done.                                                                     
Removing intermediate container 890e73a506f4                              
 ---> 8cfcd85a8252                                                        
Step 7/7 : ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Local.Proyect.Core.dll"]                
 ---> Running in d21b2ba72d9b                                             
Removing intermediate container d21b2ba72d9b                              
 ---> 7c7d08afdca2                                                        
Successfully built 7c7d08afdca2
```

But I haven't solved the problem yet. I am copying the certificate in a wrong directory inside container? And what is the correct directory to copy or what I am doing wrong. If someone have already had the same problem please let me know how to fix.